# BootstrapValidator "Cannot read property 'not' of undefined" error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [BootstrapValidator](http://formvalidation.io/) in an ASP.NET form.

To remove validation of inputs, I'm using this Javascript:

```
var $input2 = $(this).parent('.form-group').parent('td.td-multi-input').find('.input-2');    
$('#formAddSong').bootstrapValidator('removeField', $input2);
```

But sometimes I get an error like this:

[image]

Comment: can you post the HTML for the form group and input?

Comment: My code html & javascript here:
http://thuyvk.com/bootstrapValidator.txt

Comment: @Thuy.VoKhanh your JavaScript code is incomplete, i didn't see where you initialize the validator ?

Comment: @Arkni I can't see your's example?

Comment: @Thuy.VoKhanh sorry i have copied the wrong link.
here is the new one http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/adding-dynamic-field/